# Waiting for a table to be completely deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table that has to be refreshed daily from an external source. All the recommendations I read say to delete the whole table and re-create it instead of deleting all the items.

I tried the suggested method, but the `deleteTable` function returns successful even though the table is still in a state of "Table is being deleted", as seen from the DynamoDB console. Sometimes this takes more than a minute.

What is the proper way of deleting and re-creating a table? Should I just keep trying `createTable` until the already exists error goes away?

I am using Node.js.

(The table is a list of some 5,000+ bus stops. The source doesn't specify how often the data changes nor give any indicator that there are changes. I found a small number of changes once every few weeks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response from the `createTable` method is a `Table already exists` exception, the exception also contains a `retryDelay` property that is a number.

I can't find documentation on `retryDelay` but it seems to be a time duration in seconds.

I use the `Table already exists` exception to check that the table is not completely deleted, and, if not, back off for a period specified in the `retryDelay` property. After a few iterations, the table can be successfully created.

Sometimes the value in `retryDelay` can be more than 20.

This approach has worked without issues for me every time.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `boto3` (Python), there is a **waiter** called [`TableNotExists`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Waiter.TableNotExists):

> Polls `DynamoDB.Client.describe_table()` every 20 seconds until a successful state is reached. An error is returned after 25 failed checks.

Or, you could just do that polling yourself.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I am using Node.js

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest changing the table name each day, using the current date as part of the table name.  Then you can create the new table and start populating it without having to wait for the delete of the previous day's table to complete.